# *.import and *.tres files in godotengine

Tags: godot

I'm new to godotengine and want to make a project and upload it on github. I just get confused that those *.import files which are created automatically on adding a new assets and *.tres files which we make to save our tileset maps or something else are needed to be uploaded?
thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep them. Include them in your version control system. They are text based (basically INI files) and fairly small, and so play well with version control.

---

### `*.tres` files

The `*.tres` files can - and often exist - without a file that was imported. If an `*.tres` file is missing… You are screwed.

> and *.tres files which we make to save our tileset

It is not mandatory to use the "save" option on your `TileSet`. If you add a `TileMap`, give it a new `TileSet` and save the `Scene`, the `TileSet` is saved in as part of the scene file.

Saving it to a `*.tres` file will allow you reuse it (on different `TileMaps`, potentially on different scenes). And it also means it can be modified independently (which is good for version control).

Once you saved it to a `*.tres` file, that file IS your `TileSet`, it describes what sections of what textures is what tile. As I said, if the file is missing, you are screwed. You would have to do that again.

*What tile is placed where is part of the `TileMap` data, part of the scene.*

---

### `*.import` files

*There a partial here: [Godot: what are .import files, and should you commit them to git?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54249305/402022). I'll elaborate further.*

The `*.import` files include import configuration (what you set in the Import panel). Know that they must exist along side the imported file. If an `.import` file is missing Godot will re-import with the default settings (which is not good if you changed them) and recreate the `*.import` file.

It is also worth mentioning that the `*.import` files reference files in the `.import` folder (`.godot/imported` in Godot 4.0). But there is no need to include that folder. It is a read only cache, it contains duplicates of the resources in a binary format convenient for Godot (and thus not good for version control). With the original file and the `*.import` file, Godot reconstructs it.

See [Files generated on the import process](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.4/getting_started/workflow/assets/import_process.html#files-generated):

> Importing will add an extra .import file, containing the import configuration. Make sure to commit these to your version control system!